# iOS: Dumping debug data file from device to OSX

Tags: ios, file, debugging, device, dump

I am doing a lot of DSP work on iOS

So frequently I need to dump a file of raw floats, and pick it up in something like Audacity, to look at the waveform.

Even working on the simulator, this is a PITA.   I need to log the destination folder to console,  open up Finder, CTRL+CMD+G, paste the destination folder,  drag drop all of the files onto the desktop, open up Audacity, import them one by one manually correcting the format.

( Why can't I just point Audacity to the right folder once? because the iPhone simulator stores its data somewhere hideously deeply nested that involves a hidden folder, so I can't see it with the audacity file browser )

( Why is the format wrong? Because audacity tries to figure out the most likely format, and if my data starts off random which it often does, it will invariably get it wrong )

However, working on the device, I can't even see a way to get at these files.

What are my options? I am looking for maximum automation, as I do this typically hundreds of times in a particular job.